# How to make a view by clicking a Button on iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I have developed a program with UIButtons with a navigationBar, now I do not know how to get a view by clicking a Button. When I click the button it should show me a different view. I also want to know after passing to the view, how to navigate back to the before view programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You want `pushViewController:animated:` and `popViewControllerAnimated:`.

Take a look at the [UINavigationController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller).

Answer (score 0):

Also u also develop something like this,

```
CGRect cg = CGRectMake(130.0, 220.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:cg];
    btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Showlbl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

And give the proper button event in above part,

```
action:@selector(Showlbl:)
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. The coding that u have stated is fine but i want to know how to place a simple view inside the method Showlbl:. Such that whenever i press the button that action should be to view another page.